# Return an array from a function within a sub

Tags: function, vba, excel

I'm somehow new to excel VBA and I'm stuck with something that should be super easy and I hope you can help me.

I have a Sub (called test() in this case) and I want there to get an array from my function ReturnArray().

But all I get is "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" when I try to run the sub.

Thanks in Advance.

```
Function ReturnArray() As Variant
    Dim Accounts As Variant
    Accounts = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,)

    ReturnArray = Accounts
End Function
```

---

```
Sub test()
    Dim acc() As Variant
    acc = ReturnArray
    Debug.Print acc
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) remove comma: `9,)` 2) you can't print array in single loop: `Debug.Print acc`. Replace this line with loop

Comment: Also you need to Dim Acc as just a Variant `Dim acc As Variant`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dim acc() As Variant` declares `acc` as an array of variants but you are returning a single variant from your `ReturnArray` function. That single variant happens to contain an array. But just one array.

`Dim acc As Variant`

Now with that said, you are now going to get a runtime error  on `Debug.Print acc` because you cannot print out a whole array on one line. You need to loop over all the elements and print them one at a time. You can turn all the array elements into one string by joining them all together using the `Join` function: `Debug.Print Join(acc, ",")`

Comment: `Debug.Print Join(acc, ",")`

Comment: @tigeravatar, true, or you can force it all into one line by making it all one string by joining together all the elements. Updated